# Error :Undefined function 'kernelpca_tutorial' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, pca

I have rum this code

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27319-kernel-pca/content/kernelpca_tutorial.m

But I get the error as

> > kernelpca_tutorial(input,5)
> >     Undefined function 'kernelpca_tutorial' for input arguments of type 'double'.

where input is

input =

```
2.5000    3.5000    1.0000
1.5000    7.5000    9.0000
4.5000    8.0000    9.0000
```

What cud be the error..Any help wud be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are running this from a wrong directory (i.e. you are calling something that MATLAB just can't find, so the problem is not the input).

Comment: thnku  ..You wer correct .I hav been running from a wrong directory